# How do i set a layout which has a top,center, and bottom element?

Tags: android, layout, android-relativelayout

I have 2 LinearLayouts and a button within a relative layout.
They should look like this:

A LinearLayout with a top bar  (Approx. 20% of the screen)

---

Lots of elements in a scrollview which takes up most of the screen (Approx. 60% of the screen)

---

A Button at the bottom (Approx. 20% of the screen)

I have tried this:

```
<RelativeLayout
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent">

   <LinearLayout
   android:id="@+id/layoutTopBlack"
   android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content">
   <include layout="@layout/top_black_bar_cancel_register_button"/> 
</LinearLayout> 

    <LinearLayout
   android:id="@+id/layoutCenter"
   android:layout_below="@id/layoutTopBlack"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent">
   <include layout="@layout/top_black_bar_cancel_register_button"/> 
</LinearLayout> 

    <Button 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:id="@+id/buttonNextStep"
    android:text="@string/next_step"
    style="@style/mainButtonStyle"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

This does not work. The layoutCenter lays itself over the button, so i never see the button.

Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance.

Edit:
I found this from the editor:
Couldn't resolve resource @id/layoutTopBlack

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just tell your layoutCenter to layout itself above the button, something like this:

> ```
> <LinearLayout
> android:id="@+id/layoutCenter"
> android:layout_above="@id/buttonNextStep"
> android:layout_below="@id/layoutTopBlack"
> android:layout_width="fill_parent"
> android:layout_height="fill_parent">
> <include layout="@layout/top_black_bar_cancel_register_button"/> 
> </LinearLayout>
> ```

Comment: hmmm, i get Couldn't resolve resource @id/layoutTopBlack, even though i have added it with the @+id/

Comment: @Ikky how did you solve your issue with the couldn't resolve resource? I usually just move the resources around with the @+id/ until it works.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, given the percentages you mentioned, you'd probably want to use a `LinearLayout` with [layout weights](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout-objects.html#linearlayout) here, not a RelativeLayout.

EG to do the 20% / 60% / 20% weight you mentioned:

```
<LinearLayout 
  android:layout_width="match_parent" 
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:orientation="vertical">
  <View android:layout_height="0px" android:layout_weight="1" ... />
  <View android:layout_height="0px" android:layout_weight="3" ... />
  <View android:layout_height="0px" android:layout_weight="1" ... />
</LinearLayout>
```

If the top/bottom bars just need to hold their content, not take up a fixed percentage, then renam.antune's answer should work, or you could use a `LinearLayout` like above but set the top/bottom bars to wrap content without setting a weight on them. Then any weight on the center view will make it fill out all available remaining space without wiping out the button like it would with a `fill_parent`.